# How to format a json string in python

Tags: python, json, format

I have a JSON string (simplified version shown below), and I'd like to be able to format it to dynamically insert values into the "item" field:

```
"""{"a":[{"id":1,"item":{}},{"id":2,"item":{}}]}""".format(8,0)
```

I get `KeyError: '"a"'` when I do this, presumably because I need to escape all the other brackets. The actual json I have is quite a bit more complex, and it would be a pain to escape all the brackets. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the buildin json module:

```
import json
data = json.loads(yourjson)
data["a"][0]["item"] = 8
data["a"][1]["item"] = 0
text = json.dumps(dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `%` style formatting:

```
"""{"a":[{"id":1,"item":%s},{"id":2,"item":%s}]}""" % (8,0)
```

However, that still feels quite flaky.  I think it's probably better to work with python objects (e.g. `dict`, `list`) and then you can convert those objects to `JSON` using `json.dumps`.